# Finding normal distributions overlap using double Integral (dblquad) in MATLAB. Strange behaviour

Tags: matlab, statistics, normal-distribution, integral

I am calculating the overlap of two normal bivariate distribution using the following function

```
function [ oa ] = bivariate_overlap_integral(mu_x1,mu_y1,mu_x2,mu_y2)
    %calculating pdf. Using x as vector because of MATLAB requirements for integration
    bpdf_vec1=@(x,y,mu_x,mu_y)(exp(-((x-mu_x).^2)./2.-((y-mu_y)^2)/2)./(2*pi));

    %calcualting overlap of two distributions at the point x,y
    overlap_point = @(x,y) min(bpdf_vec1(x,y,mu_x1,mu_y1),bpdf_vec1(x,y,mu_x2,mu_y2));

    %calculating overall overlap area
    oa=dblquad(overlap_point,-100,100,-100,100);
```

You can see that this involves taking a double integral (x: -100 to 100, y:-100 to 100, ideally -inf to inf but suffices at the moment) from the function overlap_point which is minimum of 2 pdf-s given by the function bpdf_vec1 of two distributions at the point x,y.

Now, PDF is never 0, so I would expect that the larger the area of the interval, the larger will the end result become, obviously with the negligible difference after a certain point. However, it appears that sometimes, when I decrease the size of the interval the result grows. For instance:

```
>> mu_x1=0;mu_y1=0;mu_x2=5;mu_y2=0;
>> bpdf_vec1=@(x,y,mu_x,mu_y)(exp(-((x-mu_x).^2)./2.-((y-mu_y)^2)/2)./(2*pi));
>>  overlap_point = @(x,y) min(bpdf_vec1(x,y,mu_x1,mu_y1),bpdf_vec1(x,y,mu_x2,mu_y2));
>> dblquad(overlap_point,-10,10,-10,10)
ans =
    0.0124
>> dblquad(overlap_point,-100,100,-100,100)
ans =
    1.4976e-005  -----> strange, as theoretically cannot be smaller then the first answer
>> dblquad(overlap_point,-3,3,-3,3)
ans =
    0.0110  -----> makes sense that the result is less than the first answer as the           
interval is decreased
```

Here we can check that the overlaps are (close to) 0 at the border points of interval.

```
>> overlap_point (100,100)
ans =
 0
>> overlap_point (-100,100)
ans =
 0
>> overlap_point (-100,-100)
ans =
 0
>> overlap_point (100,-100)
ans =
 0
```

Does this perhaps have to do with the implementation of dblquad, or am I making a mistake somewhere? I use MATLAB R2011a.

Thanks

Comment: I've checked over your code and can see no mistakes, so I assume it's a precision problem with matlab (precision somehow linked to the span of the limits). I'll test your code in octave and see if it has the same problem. BTW, can you try it with the optional precision parameter, like dblquad(-100,100,-100,100,1e-8) for example.

Comment: Interestingly the problem did not arise when running the exact same code in gnu-Octave. With the default precision there was virtually no difference in the result of the integral over [-10,10,-10,10] compared with that over [-100,100,-100,100]. Both results were about 0.01241933 btw.

Comment: Can you test by gradually increasing the limits and see where it first starts to fail. Like [-30,30,-30,30] then [-40,40,-40,40] and so on until the results start to diverge. Then at that point try adding the optional precision parameter of 1e-7 or 1e-8 etc, and see if that resolves the issue. BTW. My version of Octave is 3.6.1

Comment: Thanks for comments. The result starts decreasing from [-10,10,-10,10] `>> dblquad(overlap_point,-9,9,-9,9) ans = 0.012434302954144`  `>> dblquad(overlap_point,-10,10,-10,10) ans = 0.012426083045525`. Specifying (a quite large) precision parameter does seem to have a positive effect yet does not solve the issue completely, for instance: `>> dblquad(-9,9,-9,9,1e-10) ans = 0.012419331486452`, `dblquad(-10,10,-10,10,1e-10) ans = 0.012419330851169`, `dblquad(-100,100,-100,100,1e-10) ans = 0.012415587111195` The results are much closer to each other, but still decreasing from [-10,10,-10,10].

Comment: Are these values in Octave slightly decreasing or increasing ?

Comment: "*Are these values in Octave slightly decreasing or increasing ?*" With the default precision the result does slightly decrease when going from [-10,10,-10,10] to [-100,100,-100,100], so yeah it's counter intuitive but the difference is only small (about -4e-12, so less than the target precision). When I re-evaluated them however, both with 1e-8 precision, then the [-100,100,-100,100] result was actually the larger of the two (but only be about 1e-12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CONGRATULATIONS! You win the award for being the 12 millionth person to ask essentially this question. :) What I'm trying to say is this is an issue that everyone stumbles over at first. Honestly, this question gets asked over and over again, so really, this question should be marked as a dup.

What happens with these things is a bivariate normal is essentially a delta function when viewed from far enough away. And you don't need to really spread that region out too far, since the normal density drops off fast. It is essentially zero over most of the domain you are trying to integrate over, at least to within the tolerances employed.

So then if the quadrature happens to hit some sample points near the areas where there is mass, then you may get some realistic estimate of your integral. But if all the tool sees are numbers that are essentially zero over the entire domain, it concludes the integral is zero. Remember, adaptive integration tools are NOT omniscient. They do not know anything about your function. It is a black box to them. These are NOT symbolic tools.

BTW, this is NOT something I'd expect to see consistently different for Octave versus MATLAB. It is only an issue of the adaptive integrator, and where it chooses to set its sample points down.

Comment: so, essentially the only solution is having smaller bounds for integral ?

Comment: I was not really complaining, just saying that you are not alone in tripping over this issue. I imagine we all did at one time or another.  Careful, intelligent choice of the bounds will REALLY help. Go too small however, and you lose some mass. Some of the quadrature tools allow you to specify points of interest, so if you can indicate the peaks of the normals as such, you will be far ahead. I don't recall that dblquad has such capability. I've written 2-d adaptive integration tools, and the problem is never simple to do automatically.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here are my octave results.

```
>fomat long
>z10 = dblquad(overlap_point,-10,10,-10,10)
z10 =  0.0124193303284589
>z100 = dblquad(overlap_point,-100,100,-100,100)
z100 =  0.0124193303245106
>z100 - z10
ans = -3.94835379669001e-012

>z10a = dblquad(overlap_point,-10,10,-10,10,1e-8)
z10a =  0.0124193306514996
>z100a = dblquad(overlap_point,-100,100,-100,100,1e-8)
z100a =  0.0124193306527155
>z100a-z10a
ans = 1.21588676627038e-012
```

BTW. I've noticed this type of problem before with numerical solutions. Sometimes you make a change that you expect will improve the accuracy of the result (in this case by making your limits closer to the ideal case of the full plane), but instead you get the opposite effect and the result becomes less accurate. What's happening in this case is that by going out "wider", to -100..100, you're shifting the focus away from where the really important action is happening in your function, which is close to the origin. At some point the implementation of dblquad that you're using must start increasing the intersample distance as you increase the limits, and then it starts missing some important stuff close to the origin.

Maybe someone with running a later version of matlab can check this out and see if it's been improved.